# Trigger to set ListView selected item through XAML in UWP

Tags: .net, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a ListView containing TextBoxes and I'd like to set the selected item whenever a user clicks within one of the TextBoxes.

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

            <TextBlock Text="Name  Serial"/>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}"
                      SelectedItem="{x:Bind VM.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ListView.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.Resources>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Serial, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
```

The problem is Style Triggers aren't supported in UWP. Is there some other way I can achieve this?

Comment: I haven't tried it. I don't see how it could help.

Comment: Yeah, that won't help - I've tried your sample and now understand the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, `Trigger`s can be replaced by `Behavior`s. Here's an example -

First, you will need to install this [*nuget*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/) package if you haven't got it.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed
```

Then, you want to add these namespaces to your XAML.

```
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

With these namespaces, you can now use the `EventTriggerBehavior` that comes with the *nuget* package you installed earlier. You basically need to attach it to all your `TextBox`es that control the selection.

```
<TextBox>
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="GotFocus">
            <local:SelectSelectorItemAction />
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

What `EventTriggerBehavior` does in this case is, whenever the event `GotFocus` of the `TextBox` is invoked, an `IAction` called `SelectSelectorItemAction` will be executed (via `IAction.Execute`). This `SelectSelectorItemAction` is the only thing that you will need to build.

```
public class SelectSelectorItemAction : DependencyObject, IAction
{
    public object Execute(object sender, object parameter)
    {
        var textBox = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        var selectorItem = textBox.GetParent<SelectorItem>();

        selectorItem.IsSelected = true;
        return true;
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static T GetParent<T>(this DependencyObject element) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);

        // C# 7 pattern matching feature. If you are not using C# 7, change it.
        if (parent is T p)
        {
            return p;
        }

        return GetParent<T>(parent);
    }
}
```

The code is quite straightforward. All it does is to search up the *Visual Tree* and locate the `SelectorItem`, which is the base class of `ListViewItem`. This way you can reuse the same `SelectSelectorItemAction` for `GridView` too.